# Any tooltip library for iOS that can point and highlight navigation items?

Tags: swift3, tooltip, uinavigationitem

I have tried tooltip pods like AmToolTip and EasyToolTip(that can point to navigation items) but I need toolTip that covers the whole screen with a blur overlay and highlights a particular view in navigation bar ie. navigation item.
For example The overlay option of this android library [Simple Tool Tip Demo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/douglasjunior/android-simple-tooltip/master/screenshots/demo.gif) does exactly what I want 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Instructions](https://github.com/ephread/Instructions) in iOS. It allows you to add customizable coach marks into your iOS project. Available for both iPhone and iPad. You can also customize its properties.

You can also refer [this](https://iosdeveloperblog.com/category/libraries/uiux/walkthrough-intro-tutorial/) link for more similar libraries in both Swift and Objective C.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. What should I have searched for to find this, because I searched for tooltips and I didn't find this library @Sneha